# how to pass a value to php variable by ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

this is my javascript code :

```
function  category(row){
    dataparam = "oper=delete&row="+row;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "multiupload.php",
        data: dataparam,
        error:function() {
                alert("sorry")
        },
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
```

and my php script :

```
$opers = (isset($_REQUEST['opers']) and $_REQUEST['opers'] != '' ) ? $_REQUEST['opers'] : '';
if($opers == "delete") {
        $row=$_REQUEST['row'];
        echo $row;
}
```

This is not working... I don't know what problem is. Please help me to get the `$row` variable in my php script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130662/passing-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax/?

Answer (score 1):

In your dataparam variable you have `"oper=delete&row="+row;` and in the PHP code you test for `$_REQUEST['opers'])`, since `oper` <> `opers`, the failure is perfectly normal, just add or remove the `s` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have this wrong, `$_REQUEST['opers']` it should  be `$_REQUEST['oper']`

```
$opers = (isset($_REQUEST['oper']) and $_REQUEST['oper'] != '' ) ? $_REQUEST['oper'] : '';  

if($opers == "delete") {
    $row=$_REQUEST['row'];
    echo $row;
}
```

I would also recommend that as you are expecting the values to come via URL you use the appropriate super global which is `$_GET`. There is a very small chance that a `$_COOKIE` could screw you over. If you use them and hapen to give it the value of 'oper'.

Answer (score 0):

You want `$_REQUEST['opers']` while you pass oper. Notice the additional "s".

Answer (score 0):

```
$opers = (isset($_REQUEST['oper']) and $_REQUEST['oper'] != '' ) ? $_REQUEST['oper'] : '';  
if($opers == "delete")
{
     $row=$_REQUEST['row'];
     echo $row;
}
```

Hopefully the problem is with the extra curly brackets. Check it. I have corrected the code. Let me know if it works.
And there is an extra s in opers.