# Is it possible to transfer javascript value to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php)

Let's say I have the following javascript:

```
<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
</script>
```

Now I want to get the value of today variable into PHP.

```
$cur_date = '<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(today) </script>';

echo "current date: $cur_date";

$checkin = strtotime($cur_date);
```

Although I can output the current date but how can I transfer it to $checkin variable with strtotime function?

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029298/passing-a-javascript-value-to-a-php-variable-with-limitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser. It is impossible in the way you want to do it.