# How do I send url parameters via GET method to PHP with JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

Here's my JS code...

```
function da(){
    var a=document.forms["user"]["age"].value;
    if(this.age.value < 18 || this.age.value > 85) {
        alert('some text...');
        this.age.focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        window.location.href='file.php?&'+a;
    }
}
```

It simply passes the parameters to the page where I'm standing...
Here's the form just in case (I'm a beginner keep in mind)...

```
<form name="buscar" method="GET"> Some text <input                 onmouseover="Aj2('d');document.getElementById('box').style.display='block';" onmouseout="clean();" type="number" name="age" id="age" > Age <div id="help" ><!-- --> </div><br />
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="da()">
</form>
```

The Aj2 function is not the problem here...
Thanks for any help y might get...

Comment: Use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this.

Comment: the magic word.... **AJAX** now google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a JavaScript Value to a PHP Variable (With Limitation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029298/passing-a-javascript-value-to-a-php-variable-with-limitation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, if you don't actually have to reload the page and just want to get information to your javascript code from PHP, you could do something like

```
<script>

<?
    $phpvariable = "my variable";
?>

var jsvariable = <?php echo json_encode($phpvariable); ?>;

</script>
```

Now the javascript variable, jsvariable, will hold the PHP variable's content.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this I am not a expert.

```
$('button name').on('click', function() {
   var age_ = document.getElemenetById('age');
   $.get('path of your file', {'age' : age_}, function(resp) {
        // code to pass parameter
        alert(age_);
   });
});
```