# Passing a value to a page using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the next step forward to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280767/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link)

I have the script below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
    $.get("somepage.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">Click Me!</a>
```

My question is, if I want to send a value to somepage.php page once someone click on the link, how do I do it.

My new `a` link look like this 
`<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(<?php echo $id; ?>);">Click Me!</a>`

Comment: this link might help u...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130662/passing-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
function doSomething(id) {
    $.get("somepage.php?id="+id);
    return false;
}
```

OR

```
function doSomething(id) {
    $.get("somepage.php", { id: id } );
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(myData ) {    
$.get("somepage.php" , {'data': myData } , function(result){
    });
}
```

Here the data is sent using a key value pair.. If you want to something with the returned data handle it in the callback function. Otherwise you can remove it ..