# Passing javascript variable within a javascript function to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the following javascript code. The variable dyna was originally retrieved from PHP. As the user clicks any of the buttons, the variable dyna increases/decreases by 1 with each click (depending on whether they hit the '-' button or the '+' button). My objective is to pass the javascript variable 'dyna' through a POST method to PHP.

Any advice on how this can be done?

```
 <script>

 var dyna = <?php echo $user_dyna; ?>

 $(function() {

 $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

 $(".button").on("click", function() {

  var $button = $(this);

   if ($button.text() == "+") {
     dyna -= 1;
   } else {
       dyna += 1;
       } 

       $.ajax({
       url: 'stats.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {dyna: dyna}
       });

 });

});
 </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Javascript Variable to PHP using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130662/passing-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax)

Comment: How should I write the ajax code in my case? Very unfamiliar with the use of ajax. Attempted to include ajax in my code (updated above), but not working. stats.php is the name of the file.

Comment: Time to [get familiar](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) then.

Comment: Your code above looks good to me; you're certainly using AJAX correctly. Are you sure that `dyna` is indeed updated at the time it's being sent back? And keep in mind that `stats.php` will need to *process* the `dyna` POST somehow -- `$_POST['dyna']` should contain the value -- though keep in mind this happens in the *background*; you won't see it if you visit the page yourself. To know that it was sent successfully, you can check the `response` of the POST request from the JavaScript side of things.

Comment: Obsidian Age, just to clarify, must 'stats.php' be a separate file? Or can it all occur in the same file?  Also could you explain what it means by "processing" the dyna post? Thanks for the advice!